# RPL: questions on routing mechanism

Tags: routing, wireless, ipv6, protocol-theory

I'm studying RPL and two questions came to my mind:

1: Both in storing and non-storing modes, if a node wants to send a packet to another node via P2P communication paradigm, then how does the sender node get the address of the recipient?

2: In non-storing mode, if a node wants to send a packet to other nodes (P2P or P2MP), it sends first this packet to the root of the DODAG, which forwards the packet to the right descendant, but, if (non-root) nodes do not maintain downward routes, how can they correctly forward this packet?

Comment: doubts or questions? The meaning changes significantly.

Comment: @TBR doubts that turned into questions basically